# Python docstring repeated param text

Tags: python, docstring

In a Python module (which is designed to be used in IPython Notebooks by less-technical users), I have several functions in the way of:

```
load_this(dt, this_filter)
load_that(dt, that_filter)
load_the_other(dt, the_other_filter)
```

The docstring for the dt param is the same for each function:

```
:param dt: date, date tuple, or datetime tuple. 
    date type args expand to start and end of day.
    eg.  date(2015, 9, 9) or
    (date(2015, 9, 9), date(2015, 9, 10)) or
    (datetime(2015, 9, 9, 12, 30), datetime(2015, 9, 9, 1))
```

However the docsring for x_filter params are different in each case.

I try to be as DRY as I can in my code, so the repeated docstring is grating a little. Is there any way to cross reference a docstring param in the code, but still have IPython display the full docstring.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add docs to functions via decorator

```
def mydoc(func):
    func.__doc__ = 'Here I am.'
    return func

@mydoc
def load_this(dt):
    pass
```

Variant with custom docs

```
def setdoc(docstring):
    def decor(func):
        func.__doc__ = docstring
        return func
    return decor

@setdoc('Here I am.')
def load_this(dt):
    pass
```

or just add docs after defining a function

```
docmessage = 'Here I am.'
def load_this(dt):
    pass
load_this.__doc__ = docmessage
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful.. I should have specified that I have other heterogeneous arguments in the different functions.. it's only the dt argument that is common. But, I guess I can do some string replacement with the __doc__ reference? I'm going to play with it. (Although am wary of making things too magic :))

Comment: Yes you can modify existing doc instead of replacing. By default __doc__ is None. I'll add one more example now for passing docstring to decorator as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of programmatically generating the docstring (rather unpythonic in my opinion), what stops you from just define a function `load` like

```
def load(dt, filter_):
    ... ...
```

and write a single documentation for it?  I really fail to see the need for 3 separate functions.

Even if you some how do, you can always create them, after defining the above function `load`, by [`partial`ing](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial) them.

---

Edit: After the comment by OP, I think you can simply write the doc for `dt` once in one of the functions (presumably the most basic, "prototype" one) and in other function simply say

```
"See the documentation of ___ for details about dt".
```

Yes, you can splice docstrings smartly like

```
some_function.__doc__ = some_function.__doc__ + "doc for dt"
```

or more smartly than that by writing your own documentation-generating metaclass generator factor factory framework, but why? ;)

Comment: I was expecting an answer like this ;) a) the code is designed for non-technical users. b) the filter_ args are very heterogeneous, and indeed aren't the only variation between the functions. Some functions have 2 args, some have 7.